# Wordpress plugin export to csv NO DOWNLOAD

Tags: wordpress, csv, download, export

I have a custom plugin to export a specific database table to a CSV file.

The problem is that i don't have any "Download" option... this just write the file on the screen .. I can't download it.

Here is the code

```
    function Code_CSV_export_page() {

    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){ return false; }
    if( !is_admin() ){ return false; }


    if (isset($_POST['export']))
    {
        global $wpdb, $ID_angebot;

        $ID_angebot = $_POST['ID_angebot_enter'];
        $filename =  date("Ymd") . '-' . 'Export-Angebot-' . $ID_angebot  . '.csv';

        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Pragma: public");

        $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

        $header_row = array(
            0 =>'ID ANGEBOT',
            1=>'ANGEBOT',
            2 =>'ENDDATUM',
            3 =>'FIRMENNAMEN',
            4 =>'CODE',
            5 =>'VERWENDET',
            6 =>'TITEL',
            7 =>'NACHNAME',
            8 =>'VORNAME',
            9 =>'HERUNTERLADEN DATUM'
        );
        $data_rows = array();

        $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wpPGRmaplus_angebote WHERE `id_angebot`=$ID_angebot ");
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query); 

        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            $row = array();
            $row [0] = $result -> id_angebot;
            $row [1] = $result -> angebot_name;
            $row [2] = $result -> enddatum;
            $row [3] = $result -> firmenname;
            $row [4] = $result -> code;
            $row [5] = $result -> verwendet;
            $row [6] = $result -> Titel;
            $row [7] = $result -> Nachname;
            $row [8] = $result -> Vorname;
            $row [9] = $result -> herunterladen_datum;

            $data_rows[] = $row;
        }

        //fprintf( $fh, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );

        // header avant ici
           fputcsv( $fh, $header_row );
        foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
           fputcsv( $fh, $data_row );
        }

        fclose( $fh );

        die();

     }

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">          
        <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" >
            <table class="form-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th> </br> </br> </th> </tr>
                    <tr><th> </br> </br> </th> <td style="padding-bottom:60px; font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold;">Exportcodes und ihre Benutzer </td> </tr>
                    <tr><th> </br>  </th> </tr>
                    <tr><th>ID des Angebots bezogen auf die Codeliste</th>
                    <?php $ID_angebot_enter = $custom_angebotenter["ID_angebot_enter"][0]; ?>        
                    <td style="padding-top:20px;" ><input class="regular-text" id="ID_angebot_enter" type="text" name="ID_angebot_enter" value="<?php echo $ID_angebot_enter;?>" /></br>
                    <i> <?php echo 'Die ID wird im Angebot angezeigt -> Teil "Wie benutzt man das Angebot in Wordpress?"'; ?></i> <br/>
                    <i> <?php echo 'ACHTUNG, Export der Datenbank, abhängig vom gewählten Angebot;' ?></i> <br/> <br/> <br/> </td>
            </tr>
                    <?php //récupération de l'id de l'offre
                    $ID_angebot = $_POST['ID_angebot_enter'];?>
                    <tr><th> Export in Excel File</th>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="export" value="EXPORT TO CSV"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I have searched a lot and tried so many thing.
I can't see anything more.... I need an outside eye...

Could you please help me ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Timama

Comment: write download code on init hook.

Comment: I need to code something else?

The following code doesn't propose to download a CSV ?

header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");

Answer (score 1):

you must put download code on init hook:

```
`add_action( 'init', 'downloadfunc' );
function downloadfunc() {
    if(isset($_POST['export'])) {
        //download xode goes here
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

okay I tried the hook.. buti think i am not good in hook ;-)

SO, here the code which works now  ;-)

```
function Code_CSV_export_page() {
if(is_admin()){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['exportbtn'])){
            $ID_angebot = $_POST['ID_angebot_enter'];
            if (empty($_POST['ID_angebot_enter']))
            { ?>
            <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
            <tr><th> </br> </br> </th> </tr>
            <tr><th> </br>  </th> </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="color:red";>VORSICHT</th>
                        <td style="color:red";> - Bitte, nicht vergessen die Angebots-ID - </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr><th> </br>  </th> </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th> <a href="https://programm-maplus.de/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=angebote&page=Code_CSV_export"> Zur Export Plugin</a></th>
                        <td>  </td>
                    </tr> 

                    <?php exit();
            }

                ob_clean();
                $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
                $header_row = array(
                    0 =>'ID ANGEBOT',
                    1 =>'ANGEBOT',
                    2 =>'ENDDATUM',
                    3 =>'FIRMENNAMEN',
                    4 =>'CODE',
                    5 =>'VERWENDET',
                    6 =>'TITEL',
                    7 =>'NACHNAME',
                    8 =>'VORNAME',
                    9 =>'HERUNTERLADEN DATUM'
                );
                $data_rows = array();
                $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wpPGRmaplus_angebote WHERE `id_angebot`=$ID_angebot ");
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($query); 

                foreach ( $results as $result ) {
                    $row = array();
                    $row [0] = $result -> id_angebot;
                    $row [1] = $result -> angebot_name;
                    $row [2] = $result -> enddatum;
                    $row [3] = $result -> firmenname;
                    $row [4] = $result -> code;
                    $row [5] = $result -> verwendet;
                    $row [6] = $result -> Titel;
                    $row [7] = $result -> Nachname;
                    $row [8] = $result -> Vorname;
                    $row [9] = $result -> herunterladen_datum;
                    $data_rows[] = $row;
                }

                fputcsv( $fh, $header_row,"\t", '"' );
                foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
                   fputcsv( $fh, $data_row ,"\t", '"');
                }
                fprintf( $fh, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );

                header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".date('Ymd')."-"."Export-Angebot-".$ID_angebot.".xls");  //File name extension was wrong
                header("Expires: 0");
                header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                header("Cache-Control: private",false);
                }
        ?>
         <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post" id="export-form">
            <table class="form-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th> </br> </br> </th> </tr>
                 <tr><th> </br> </br> </th> <td style="padding-bottom:60px; font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold;">Exportcodes und ihre Benutzer </td> </tr>
                    <tr><th> </br>  </th> </tr>
                    <tr><th>ID des Angebots bezogen auf die Codeliste</th>
                    <?php  $ID_angebot_enter = $custom_angebotenter["ID_angebot_enter"][0]; ?>        
                    <td style="padding-top:20px;" ><input class="regular-text" id="ID_angebot_enter" type="text" name="ID_angebot_enter" value="<?php echo $ID_angebot_enter;?>" /></br>
               <i> <?php echo 'Die ID wird im Angebot angezeigt -> Teil "Wie benutzt man das Angebot in Wordpress?"'; ?></i> <br/>
                <i> <?php echo 'ACHTUNG, Export der Datenbank, abhängig vom gewählten Angebot;' ?></i> <br/> <br/> <br/> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr><th> Export in Excel File</th>
               <td> <input class="button button-primary exportbtn" name="exportbtn" type="submit" name="table_display" value="Export"/></td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php } }
```

Comment: SOLVED !!if this can help someone